# Ported python3 csv module to C# what license should I use for my module?

Tags: python, module, licensing

I have ported python3 csv module to C# what license could I use for my module? 
Should I distribute my module? 
Should I put PSF copyright in every header of my module?

thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why? Surely there is a .NET library for handling CSV files, isn't there?

Comment: What does the existing license say you can do?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker I have tried to use .Net libraries ([FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) and [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) but they failed to parse my exzotic csv fromat from third party legacy system. Python csv module parsed that csv format.

Comment: @phkahler as I understand build-in modules uses python (PSF) license. I have read it but I don't understand what license derived work must use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pay a copyright lawyer to tell you that. But my guess is that you need to use the PSF license. Note that PSF does not have the copyright to Python source code. They coders do how that copyright translates into you making a C# port is something only a copyright expert can say. Also note that it is likely to vary from country to country.

Copyright sucks.